# External Microphone Not Detecting in linux deepin

Tags: linux, debian, pulseaudio

I had a problem from last night that i can't see my external microphone that included in my headphone,
I can hear output sound perfect buy my input device is not shown in `alsamixer` and `pavucontrol`!

it's first time that i try to use my external mic!
My internal mic is works but it's useless!

Comment: What type of audio jack are you using? A microphone jack, or a combo (headphone + microphone) jack?

Comment: @dianhenglau it's a combo, but finally, I had to buy a new sound card and it's working fine now.